# Is there a jetbot python module located on the image for the jetbot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nvidia, robotics

I am pretty new to robotics and software in general. I have finished assembling my NVIDIA Jetbot and have successfully tested it using the collision avoidance notebook.

In the notebook, and in the other notebooks, it looks like their importing a module called `jetbot`. Or at least their importing classes from `jetbot`. In any case i cannot find the `jetbot` module on the jetson nano and when i use VS code to try and go to its definition, it is not able to find it that way either, although that might not be too surprising because it might not know a path to it either.

Does anyone know where i might be able to find that module?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the jetbot is connected to your computer.